# Why lodash uses switch-case in negate function?

Tags: javascript, lodash

The following code is the source code of `negate` function in lodash. As we can see that when the length of parameters less than 4, it uses `switch-case` instead of using `apply` directly. What magic about this code? Does it make the performance better? And why the split point is 4?

```
function negate(predicate) {
  if (typeof predicate != 'function') {
    throw new TypeError(FUNC_ERROR_TEXT);
  }
  return function() {
    var args = arguments;
    switch (args.length) {
      case 0: return !predicate.call(this);
      case 1: return !predicate.call(this, args[0]);
      case 2: return !predicate.call(this, args[0], args[1]);
      case 3: return !predicate.call(this, args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    }
    return !predicate.apply(this, args);
  };
}
```

Comment: Not sure but I guess `switch` performs better than `if..else` ladder. Plus, less typing.

Comment: OP's question is not why it uses `switch` instead of `if..else`. The question is why there is a conditional at all.

Comment: The split point is 4, I guess, because you shouldn' t have function that takes more than 3 parameters in oop (and also it would be quite painful and boring to hard code more cases by hand, unless you like to repeat yourself). And they probably did a benchmark too, `apply` is probably slower than the `call` method.

Answer (score 0):

Sry, but my crystal ball is still in repair. So I can only give you my best guess about the intentions of the author.

I think the point here is not about the `switch` but rather to enable the optimizer to convert this whole construct into a a single one of these paths, assuming the function will be called with a consistent set of arguments.

basically optimizing this whole constuct away and even inlining the function body of the `predicate` into something like this pseudocode.
assuming the function was always called with 2 arguments

```
function(){
    //a gate to ensure the optimization is still correct/applicable
    //probably more complex than this
    if(arguments.length === 2){          
        //assign predicate function args
        var value = arguments[0], index = arguments[1];
        [function body of predicate]
    }else{
        [de-optimize]
        //execute the de-optimized version of this function
    }
}
```

Why 0..3 arguments? imo, these are the most common cases. And the default case is only there for completeness and (again, my opinion) should never/rarely been hit.

Another point may be, that `Function#call()` is in my experience a bit faster than `Function#apply()`. Rarely enough to even think about it, but this is a lib that will be used by other libraries, so every performance issue may increase exponetially.